# Nothing happens when I click my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am having an issue that when I click my chrome extension, nothing is happening at all.  I would expect there to be an alert box.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
   "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon-gif.png",
      "default_title": "AlertBoxer"
   },
   "description": "Use this extension to see an alert box",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon-gif.png",
      "19": "icon-gif.png",
      "48": "icon-gif.png"
   },
   "name": "C3P0",
   "permissions": ["notifications"],
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and the background.js file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        alert("Hi");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to change the:

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.js"
    },
```

to:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

updated original post to show.